# Create Github Token to give user access to git clone

Tags: github, token

Does anyone have an idea on which scope to choose when creating github token to give someone access to git clone a private repository? I tried using the `repo` scope but this give them full access to modify the code on github.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub doesn't provide a token scope that limits access to reading private repositories. If you want to provide an HTTP token that grants read access to a private repository, you'll need to use the `repo` scope, which also provides access to write to the repository.

Alternately, you can let them provide you an SSH key, and you can add it as a read-only deploy key, which will restrict their access to reading data.